# How to negate a substring only in a certain section of the string with regex?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I'm trying to achieve the following thing:
I want to negate the appearance of the substring '::' but only in a certain section of the string.
For example:

a<anyStringWithout'::'>b<anyStringAlsoWith'::'>

I tried to do that with negative lookahead like this:

```
a(?!.*::).*b
```

But occurrences of '::' after 'b' also make the string to unmatch, for example: 'acb::'

Is there a way to achieve what I want with regex?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `a(?![^ab]*::)[^ab]*b` or something similar. Are `a` and `b` just placeholders for longer patterns?

Comment: Yes, they are placeholders.
Also, can you explain please why negating 'a'?
As I say, between`a` and `b` can be any string, just not '::'

Comment: When you restrict a match, you need to define the boundaries. Try `a(?:(?!a|b|::).)*b`. This matches any string that starts with `a` pattern, then matches any char that does not start the `a`, `b` and `::` patterns, zero or more times, up to the `b` pattern.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
a(?:(?!a|b|::).)*b
```

This matches any string that starts with `a` pattern, then matches any char that does not start the `a`, `b` and `::` patterns, zero or more times, up to the `b` pattern.

**Details**

- `a` - an `a` pattern
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `(?!a|b|::)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is `a`, `b` or `::` immediately to the right of the current location
  - `.` - any char but a line break char
- `)*` - zero or more times
- `b` - a `b` pattern.